# Server Doesn't Listen Error when connecting to PostgreSQL from Client

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have done a lot of research through the Google and have not been able to come up with a solution. I installed PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGIS 2.1.8 On Ubunutu Server 14.04 and configured PostgreSQL as per [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) tutorial. In genral the tutorial says to:

1. Configure pg_hba.conf to include `host all all 192.168.1.0/24 md5`; obviously inserting my ip address and I wanted password verification.

   ```
    # DO NOT DISABLE!
    # If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
    # database superuser can access the database using some other method.
    # Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
    # maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
    #
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                peer
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     peer
    # IPv4 local connections:
    # host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5`
   ```
2. Configure postgresql.conf to include `listen_addresses='*'`
3. Configure iptables firewall rules; I did this as follows:[image]

I restarted networking and PostgreSQL, then attempted to connect through PgAdmin III on a Windows Client and a Server Doesn't Listen Error[image]

The server PostgreSQL log is as follows:

2016-01-18 14:45:04 EST [7510-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-01-18 14:45:04 EST [7509-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-01-18 14:45:04 EST [7514-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-01-18 14:45:04 EST [7516-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2016-01-18 15:42:17 EST [7509-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2016-01-18 15:42:17 EST [7509-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2016-01-18 15:42:17 EST [7514-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2016-01-18 15:42:17 EST [7511-1] LOG:  shutting down
2016-01-18 15:42:17 EST [7511-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2016-01-18 15:42:18 EST [7802-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-01-    18 15:42:17 EST
2016-01-18 15:42:18 EST [7802-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-01-18 15:42:18 EST [7801-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-01-18 15:42:18 EST [7806-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-01-18 15:42:18 EST [7808-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2016-01-18 18:56:51 EST [7801-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2016-01-18 18:56:51 EST [7801-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2016-01-18 18:56:51 EST [7806-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2016-01-18 18:56:51 EST [7803-1] LOG:  shutting down
2016-01-18 18:56:51 EST [7803-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2016-01-18 18:56:53 EST [10519-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at     2016-01-18 18:56:51 E$
2016-01-18 18:56:53 EST [10519-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-01-18 18:56:53 EST [10518-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-01-18 18:56:53 EST [10523-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-01-18 18:56:53 EST [10525-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet

I am not sure what I am missing.FYI, I am generally a Ubuntu noob. I know enough to be dangerous, so please, if you are willing think laymen terms.

Comment: @JayCummins, I don"t disagree, but the fact may of the GIS community utilize PostgreSQL and PostGIS in conjunction with QGIS, I believe it wouldn't be that far off to have someone in this community provide the ultimate answer due to similar situation. Since I am a GIS user and not a Database Administrator, I went to the community that I know.

Comment: @PolyGeo if it appropriate to be moved, please do so. I appreciate the time that you put forth.

Comment: @LandArch - I think this has come up before, but I can't find the discussion in meta. But this is one of those questions where it is natural to arrive at gis.se, especially if one isn't aware of dba.se.  iirc, the discussion on meta was regarding questions like this that will inevitably resurface on gis.se after they've been moved to their final destination.

Comment: @jjanes, I added a snippet of the log above.

Comment: Could you please post the textual information as actual text?  It helps reading your post enormously.

Comment: @dezso I am not very good with the formatting and an trying to get it to work appropriately.

Comment: And post the whole `pg_hba.conf` file, not just one row. The order matters in pg_hba.

Comment: @LandArch the log looks pretty up there, I don't see where your problem is ;)  Other than that, the log lines don't contain anything relevant (which is not surprising, given the error you get).  BTW, are the restarts initiated by you?

Comment: @dezso, yes they are, I was tweaking things in the conf files based upon my research on Google. I believe the incomplete startup packet is the "error: that I get from PgAdmin III.

Comment: @ypercube, I will see what I can post later today.

Comment: From the PostgreSQL log, it is not even aware anyone is trying to connect.  So probably still a problem with the firewall, or with `selinux` or something similar.

Comment: @ypercube, I added the relevant portion of the configuration file. Not sure why the formatting is wacky though.

Comment: Try to disable the iptables rules and then the connection.  Can you log in locally from an SSH session (`psql -h localhost -U someuser`)?

Comment: Can you get us the output of `netstat -an | grep 5432`?

Comment: Did you check the outgoing firewall on your Windows install, where you're running PGAdmin III? It may be blocking outbound connections on 5432.